# Select data where condition matches and if none, then select all?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
select * from (values
    ('dept1','user1'),
    ('dept2','user2'),
    ('dept3','user3'),
    ('dept4','user4')
    )table1([department],[user])
where [user] = @id
```

scenario1:
     @id = 'user1'

```
dept1
```

scenario2: 
    @id = 'user5'

```
dept1
dept2
dept3
dept4
```

this is what it looks like from a noobish query

```sql
declare @id varchar(12) = 'user1'
declare @var int = (select count(*) from table1 where [user] = @id)

select * from table1 where [user] = @id or @var = 0
```

Comment: What is your question here exactly? Can you explain what those scenarios are? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i need a query that will select all data if user doesn't exists in the table. if there is,then select only the data that matches. i'll edit my content. hope it would help.

Comment: no help. i cant make a query that would be more helpful. let me give my existing query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @tab table (id int , value varchar(10))
declare @id int = 4

insert into @tab
select 1,'Ajay'
union all
select 2,'Ajay1'
union all
select 3,'Ajay2'
union all
select 4,'Ajay3'
union all
select 5,'Ajay4'

select * from @tab 
where id = case when exists (select * from @tab where id = @id) then @id else id end
```

Comment: it didnt go well. it ended up selecting all data.

Comment: this is fine. i hope case when exists is an easy task for my server when this data get larger and larger. thanks

Comment: @ajespiritu - Create an index on the user column. This will then be faster when the table gets large with more users in it.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(5) = 'user1';
--DECLARE @id VARCHAR(5) = 'user5';
  WITH  UsersAndDepartments
AS ( SELECT   *
    FROM     ( VALUES ( 'dept1', 'user1'), ( 'dept2', 'user2'),
            ( 'dept3', 'user3'), ( 'dept4', 'user4') ) x ( [department], [user] )
    )
SELECT  *
FROM    UsersAndDepartments ud1
WHERE   ud1.[user] = 
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM UsersAndDepartments ud2 WHERE ud2.[user] = @id ) THEN @id
        ELSE ud1.[user] 
    END
```

The above just checks on user column if any row exists for an id, else matches on all.

Comment: thanks. you had the same answer as @Ajay. he just got it early.

Comment: Cheers. the early bird gets the worm!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a simple `OR`, not a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE`.

In general, you want to avoid `CASE` expressions in the `WHERE` clause for several reasons:

- The logic can almost be written concisely using basic boolean operations.
- Adding additional constructs (in addition to `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT`) just makes the logic harder for people to follow.
- It pretty much kills any optimization paths.

I would suggest:

```
with table1 as 
      select v.*
      from (values ('dept1', 'user1'),
                   ('dept2', 'user2'),
                   ('dept3', 'user3'),
                   ('dept4', 'user4')
           ) v([department], [user])
     )
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.[user] = @id or
      not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.user = @id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to do a check first something like this

```
Declare @RowCount int
Select @RowCount = (select count(*) from [Table] Where [Column] = 'xxx')

If @RowCount > 0
 begin 
  Select 1 -- put code here if records
 end
else
 begin
  Select 2 -- put code here if no records
 end
```

Comment: that's doable. but i'll end up eating RAM just by selecting the number of data before doing the code. we're talking about big numbers of data here.

Comment: Add an index on the user column

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
DECLARE @id varchar(12) = 'user1'

IF EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE [user] = @id)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE [user] = @id
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM table1
END
```

you can also read more about "EXISTS" syntax on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You can have a slightly better execution plan if you separate the "if exist" logic from the actual query:

```
DECLARE @id varchar(10) = 'user5'
DECLARE @table TABLE ([department] varchar(10), [user] varchar(10))

insert into @table values 
                    ('dept1','user1'),
                    ('dept2','user2'),
                    ('dept3','user3'),
                    ('dept4','user4')

DECLARE @exists BIT = 
(SELECT 1 FROM @table WHERE [user] = @id)

SELECT department FROM @table
WHERE [user] = CASE @exists WHEN 1 THEN @id ELSE [user] END
```